# HDD with Windows 7 to SSD with Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-10, ssd

I recently bought a SSD drive to install my operating system there. My issue is the following:

I am running Windows 7 on a HDD drive in my current PC, and I have a copy of Windows 10 ready to install. What I was thinking to do was to install Windows 10 directly on on my SSD, and plug in my old HDD with Windows 7 installed after I boot W10. However I don´t really know how this is going to affect my files and such, or even if it works. Is it possible to do this this way? Would I lose my files? If files aren´t lost, how would they appear in my new W10 sistem?

Also, I´m planning to buy a new MOBO soon. Right now I have an Asus H81M-K and I was planning on buying a Gigabyte Z97X-UD5H-BK. Would there be any problem with the hardware change? Would you recommend to wait until I have the new MOBO and then switching to W10?

I´m sorry for the amount of questions on this issue, I´m actually super confused on how to proceed. Thanks in advance for the advise!

Answer (score 2):

New SSD will require you to ring Microsoft; new mobo will require you to ring Microsoft - I'd be tempted to do both at once & save a phone call.

Use something like Acronis with its [universal restore](http://www.acronis.com/en-gb/business/universal-restore/?adpos=1t1&creative=74336888214&device=c&matchtype=e&network=g&gclid=CjwKEAiAp_WyBRD37bGB_ZO9qAYSJAA72IkgS-BlY0QqLb2zOh8rj2PPeBbk68wi9TQBLkY-1KulcBoCkSnw_wcB), (now available on both business & home versions) to clone your Win7 to SSD in a USB enclosure, swap that to the new mobo, remove the original drive & boot. Get the authorisation sorted with MS [assuming they'll let you change both at once] & then update to win 10.

Comment: I approved of this answer.  Its really good advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Would I lose my files?

If you install Windows 10 on your SSD.  The files on your current HDD wouldn't even be touched.

> if files are not lost, how would they appear in my new Windows 10
>   system?

Only if you attach your HDD to the system they would be.

> Would there be any problem with the hardware change?

This could cause problems.  It entirely depends on if your Windows 7 license is an OEM license or not.

> Would you recommend to wait until I have the new MOBO and then
>   switching to W10?

Windows 10 activation is based on a digital entitlement.  This entitlement is based the machine's hardware.  Microsoft considers a machine to be the motherboard.  A retail license of Windows 7 can be activated on multiple machines.  The Windows 10 license provided to you for free, is limited to a single machine, but your original user rights granted to you still remain.

You are entitled to a single license to Windows 10 because of your Windows 7 license.  In other words if you install Windows 7 on the machine, after the motherboard upgrade, and upgrade to Windows 10 you are within your rights to do so.

Depending on certain factors even an OEM license of Windows can be transferred.  If you live in a region, where that is a case, contact Microsoft for a Windows 10 license that can be transferred.

Starting with Windows 10 Version 1511, Windows 10 can be installed and activated with a Windows 7 license.  This is only possible if you use an updated .ISO, which is the only version, currently be distributed by Microsoft.

Comment: Maybe I wasn´t clear on this, but what I have is a CD with Windows 10 and a serial key, given to me from the company I´m currently working at. However it seems pretty clear that I should just wait until I get my new MOBO and do all at once.

Comment: @TomasRocchi - Why does that change anything?  You can download the current Windows 10 .ISO and create your own installation media. by downloading the Media Creation Tool or directly from MS's Techbench